# Kernel recompile fails using source found in /usr/src/kernels on CentOS 8

Tags: kernel, wifi

The goal is to get the WiFi driver to load for a USB adapter using a Realtek 8812au chip. I've ran make and make install successfully on the driver using source code I found [here](https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au).

Tried modprobe on it which failed with the below (seen in dmesg):

```
Unknown symbol wireless_send_event (err 0)
```

Googled that and it appears my kernel is missing some wifi extension options. So I figure I need to recompile my kernel.

I found that the current kernel source is already present in this directory:

```
/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64
```

So I ran

```
make menuconfig
```

And selected those WiFi options, then saved the config file to .config and then ran

```
make
```

which fails with:

```
  DESCEND  objtool
/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.build:37: /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64/tools/build/Build.include: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64/tools/build/Build.include'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:43: /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64/tools/objtool/fixdep-in.o] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.include:4: fixdep] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:63: objtool] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1655: tools/objtool] Error 2
```

The build directory exists but there is no Build.include in it. Which makes me wonder if I shouldn't be recompiling from this location.

I looked at [this CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel) which is not clear about getting the source and it appears to push back on getting the source.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem. Found something related...https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1440857